# Undo or reverse YouTube update on my Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: youtube

I recently updated YouTube on my Galaxy S4 and I don't like the changes. Can I undo the update or return my android to a couple of days ago? Or do I have to live with it as it is? Thanks for your suggestions. BTW, please give me directions step by step. I'm technologically illiterate.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a system app, you should be able to uninstall updates by long pressing the icon, dragging it to "App Info", tapping the overflow menu at the top right, and tap the "uninstall updates option"

Next, go to settings>security>unknown sources and check the box.

Finally, go to [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com), search for YouTube, and download the 2nd most recent apk (choose ARM Varient) and open it.

Enjoy the older YouTube version.